# Is Difference in Difference estimator an annual effect?

Tags: regression, difference-in-difference

Hi I have a difference in difference framework with multiple pre-periods and post-periods.
I get the coefficient of Treatment * Post from the DiD regression. Is this coefficient an annual effect? ( My data is at the level of Individual-Year) If so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DID with user-level annual data estimates the annual change in the outcome for the treated individuals, averaged over the post periods.

It's an annual effect because your data is annual.

It's an average over the post periods because your model restricts the effect to be the same in every post period by using a single post dummy rather than a sequence of time dummies. The latter would allow the effect to vary over time, one for every year. You could also use something in between, say, a post1 dummy for the first post-treatment year to capture the transition and a post2+ dummy for every year after to measure the stable change once the adaptation/learning period is over. Theory and domain knowledge should be your guide to how to model the effect.

Comment: Thanks dimitriy! This is super helpful!